Adding Edge Color to the Network Graph using Networkx package



PATY_HI
PATY_LO
MATCH_KEY
WEIGHT_BUCKET




12345
6789
T
r


54321
3456
A;T
b


34567
12345
EP;T
y



I'm using the Networkx package to create a visualisation of the associations of a customer, so the user can enter a customer number and all the related information would come up. I have written a code for the same. There are two columns containing the first level customer information (PATY_HI and PATY_LO), two columns for containing the details of how the customers are associated and a WEIGHT column. Now I have created the graph, and I want to color the edges according to the weight column. The issue that I'm facing is, the color of the edges are only populating correctly when the user input is present in PATY_HI, when the user input is present in PATY_LO, the edge color is not coming. I'm not able to fix the same. Can anyone please help me in solving the same? Here's the code that I have written for the edge color. So with reference to the table given, when the user input is present in PATY_HI as 12345, the edge color is populating correctly as red, with reference to the example given, but in case when 12345 is present under PATY_LO, the edge color yellow is not coming up.
Code I have written:
Filter dataframe based on selected PATY_HI value
# Apply the format_cif function to the user input
cif = format_cif(cif)

# Get the active Snowflake session
session = get_active_session()

def network_graph(df_1, paty_hi):

    # Filter dataframe based on selected PATY_HI value
    filtered_df = df_1[(df_1['PATY_HI'] == paty_hi) | (df_1['PATY_LO'] == paty_hi)]
    
    # Sort the dataframe by the date column in descending order
    filtered_df = filtered_df.sort_values('EXPY_D', ascending=False)
    
    # Create an empty graph
    G = nx.Graph()
    
    # Adding the nodes using CustomerIDs from both columns
    G.add_nodes_from(filtered_df['PATY_HI'], label='')
    G.add_nodes_from(filtered_df['PATY_LO'], label='')
    
    # Dictionary to store the latest match_key for each pair of nodes
    latest_match_key = {}
    
    # Add edges to the graph based on associations
    for _, row in filtered_df.iterrows():
        paty_hi = row['PATY_HI']
        paty_lo = row['PATY_LO']
        match_key = row['MATCH_KEY']
        
        # Only add the edge if it's the latest match_key for the pair
        if (paty_hi, paty_lo) not in latest_match_key:
            G.add_edge(paty_hi, paty_lo)
            latest_match_key[(paty_hi, paty_lo)] = match_key

    # Define the default color
    default_color = 'black'
    
    # Set node labels based on PATY_HI, PATY_HI_NAME, PATY_LO, and PATY_LO_NAME
    node_labels = {}
    for _, row in filtered_df.iterrows():
        if row['PATY_HI'] not in node_labels:
            node_labels[row['PATY_HI']] = row['PATY_HI_NAME']
        if row['PATY_LO'] not in node_labels:
            node_labels[row['PATY_LO']] = row['PATY_LO_NAME']
    
    # Set edge weights based on the latest match_key
    edge_weights = {}
    for (paty_hi, paty_lo), match_key in latest_match_key.items():
        edge_weights[(paty_hi, paty_lo)] = match_key


    # Set edge colors based on the weight bucket
    edge_colors = {}
    for _, row in filtered_df.iterrows():
        paty_hi = row['PATY_HI']
        paty_lo = row['PATY_LO']
        weight_bucket = row['WEIGHT_BUCKET']
        
        if pd.notnull(weight_bucket):  # Check if the weight bucket is not NaN
            if (paty_hi, paty_lo) not in edge_colors:
                edge_colors[(paty_hi, paty_lo)] = weight_bucket
    
    # Replace NaN values with a default color
    default_color = 'black'
    edge_colors = {k: v if pd.notnull(v) else default_color for k, v in edge_colors.items()}

        

    #Adding Abbreviations to the graph
    abbrev_dict ={
        "A": "Address",
        "J": "Account",
        "R": "Declared Relationship",
        "P": "Contact Number",
        "E": "Email",
        "F": "Application",
        "T": "Transaction",
        "$Sent": "Color Codes",
        "T - Blue": "<$50",
        "T - Yellow": "<$500",
        "T - Red": "$500+",
        "$Received": "Black",
    }

    # Adding the abbreviation legend
    def add_abbrev_legend(fig, abbrev_dict):
        legend_text = "\n".join([f"{key}: {value}" for key, value in abbrev_dict.items()])
        fig.text(1.2, 1, f"Legend:\n{legend_text}", fontsize=60, bbox=dict(facecolor='yellow', edgecolor='black', boxstyle='round,pad=0.5'))
        

    # Set font and font color
    font = {'fontname': 'Arial', 'color': 'black'}

    
    # Check the distinct count of PATY_HI and PATY_LO
    distinct_count = len(set(filtered_df['PATY_HI']).union(set(filtered_df['PATY_LO'])))

    # Visualize the graph with the appropriate layout
    if distinct_count <= 2:
        plt.figure()
        pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=0.5)
        nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True, labels=node_labels, node_color='yellow', node_size=3000, font_size=20,
                font_color=font['color'], alpha=0.7,
                edge_color=[edge_colors.get((u, v), default_color) for u, v in G.edges()], width=3.0)
    elif distinct_count <= 4:
        plt.figure(figsize=(50, 50))
        pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
        nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True, labels=node_labels, node_color='yellow', node_size=8000, font_size=60,
                font_color=font['color'], alpha=0.99,
                edge_color=[edge_colors.get((u, v), default_color) for u, v in G.edges()], width=5.0)
    else:
        plt.figure(figsize=(50, 50))
        pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=0.3)
        nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True, labels=node_labels, node_color='yellow', node_size=8000, font_size=60,
                font_color=font['color'], alpha=0.99,
                edge_color=[edge_colors.get((u, v), default_color) for u, v in G.edges()], width=5.0)

    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos=pos, edge_labels=edge_weights, font_size=70, font_color=font['color'])
    add_abbrev_legend(plt, abbrev_dict)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()

    return G

I tried writing this but when the user input is present in PATY_LO, the edge color is still taking the degfault color as black
